# Use String in SWI Prolog

Tags: string, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm a little bit confused.
I would like to use the split_string function which can be seen [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=strings).
But I just don't know how to import or use this function. Do I have this pl File already on my PC? I can only find strings.pl in C:\Program Files\swipl\library\dialect\ciao but I doesn't include the split_string function.

I'm pretty sure it's totally easy but I just can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably need to install the "development release" of SWI-Prolog (major version 7), if you haven't yet. On Windows and MacOS, this simply means getting the right [binaries](http://www.swi-prolog.org/download/devel). For Linux, you can either add the PPA (on the same page), or [build from source](http://www.swi-prolog.org/build/), which is straight-forward enough.

Then, you will get something along the lines of: (note the banner with the version number)

```
$ swipl
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 7.1.25)
Copyright (c) 1990-2014 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Please visit http://www.swi-prolog.org for details.

For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- split_string("a.b.c", ".", "", L).
L = ["a", "b", "c"].
```

You shouldn't need to import anything explicitly.

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: I encountered a problem a problem with SWI7 and had to return to SWI6.
Is there are possibility to use something like split string in SWI6?

Comment: @Tim you get a lot of overlapping functionality between strings and atoms. But there is really no reason to stick to SWI6, if you are going to be using SWI-Prolog.

Comment: Thanks, I found out that **atomic_list_concat** does what i need.
I have to stick with SWI6 because of the problem found here: http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/SWI7_and_ISO

Comment: @Tim This is not a problem, really. This page lists a bunch of corner cases in which SWI-Prolog departs from strict ISO-Prolog compliance. This is a far cry from making the implementation "broken", it is simply different for some convoluted examples. There are many other issues with SWI6, too, in regards to ISO-compliance. My point was, for "learning", yes, stick to SWI6. For real-world developments, move on to SWI7 or pick another implementation.

Comment: @Tim I cannot agree that the examples where SWI differs are all convoluted. Take `writeq('.'(3,[])).` which is canonical syntax in ISO Prolog, that is, it can be read regardless of the current operator declarations, but SWI7 rejects this. That means: It is impossible to reliably recover "serialized" Prolog terms in SWI. The situation is even worse: SWI7 cannot reliably read its own terms back (in the presence of strings). Since SWI7 uses a lot of strings by default, this means that there is no longer a reliable way to store data in a non-proprietary way. This makes SWI7 seriously broken.